# Its is possible to create Realm in (Keycloak or RH-SSO) throught the CLI - GUI?

Tags: keycloak, redhat-sso

Is it possible to create Realm through the CLI - GUI?

I would like to know if it is possible to create a realm via CLI - GUI. (I started the gui with the command “. \ Jboss-cli.sh --gui”)

If possible, how can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty certain you can't use the Jboss-cli for that, but you can use kcadm.sh to manage realms and clients. See official [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#using-the-admin-cli).
It just uses Keycloak's [rest endpoints](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html), so you could use another tool to make those requests if you wish e.g postman/newman.

However if you require a GUI, why not just use the web based admin panel?
If it is running on a remote server you can use ssh with the [-N flag](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) to forward the remote port to some local port which you can access with your browser.